How to Run a Query Only Once Before a Scheduled Interval in an Airflow DAG?
I have a DAG to create reports that looks like this:
from airflow import DAG

dag = DAG(
    'send_reports', 
    schedule_interval='0 6 * * 5', 
    default_args=dag_args
)

def create_report(agent):
    # Logic to create and send report

def get_agents_list():
    # Logic to run query on Redshift and fetch agent list

with dag:
    agents = get_agents_list()
    for agent in agents:
        create_report(agent)

The get_agents_list function runs a query on Redshift to fetch a list of agents, and create_report creates a task for every agent. The problem is that each time the Airflow workers refresh, the query is executed again, leading to unnecessary database load.
How can I modify the DAG so that the get_agents_list query runs only once before the DAG's scheduled interval, avoiding redundant query executions each time the workers refresh? Thanks.
